# Why is this Fermat primality tester giving me an exception?

Tags: c#, primes

Why is this Fermat primality tester giving me an exception?

```
class PrimeTest
{
    public static bool IsPrime(long n, int iteration = 5)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        long a = 0;
        long aPow = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < iteration; i++)
        {
            a = r.Next(1, Convert.ToInt32(n - 1));

            double x = Convert.ToDouble(a);
            double y = Convert.ToDouble(n - 1);
            double p = Math.Pow(x, y);

            aPow = Convert.ToInt64(p);//<==== this line is giving an exception.

            if (1 % n == aPow % n)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", PrimeTest.IsPrime(33));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.
```

Comment: Seems like the exception is pretty clear. The value `p` is not within the range allowed for a `long`. See marked duplicate, which pretty much the identical problem, just for `int` instead of `long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `a` is a random number [1~n-1], and a^(n-1) could be easily larger than `Int64.Max`
For example, a=10 and 10^32 is greater than Int64.Max.

```
        Random r = new Random();
        long a = 0;
        long aPow = 0;

        for( int i = 0; i < iteration; i++ ) {
            a = r.Next( 1, Convert.ToInt32( n - 1 ) );

            // p is 1E32; if a==10
            double p = Math.Pow( Convert.ToDouble( a ), Convert.ToDouble( n - 1 ) );

            // Int64 is 9223372036854775807, which is less than 1E32
            aPow = Convert.ToInt64( p ); //giving exception

            if( 1 % n == aPow % n ) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Running your program, I got:

`3.4336838202925124E+30`, or `3433683820292512400000000000000`

And the max value for a `Int64` or `long` is `9223372036854775807`

It's pretty easy to see why you're getting an `Overflow Exception`.  If you look at the message, you'll see some more details:

`Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.`

That number is much too large to fit into a `long` value.

Comment: I don't know this algorithm.  But your question was `Why is code this giving me this exception?`